# Is there any configuration needed on Windows server 2008 R2 for using SessionAuthenticationModule?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-server-2008-r2, wif, claims-based-identity

I am using WIF and SessionAuthenticationModule for a claim based authentication and authorization in my MVC application.
Now almost everything works fine. But when I deploy it on server(Windows Server 2008 R2 and .Net 4.5.2 installed) it has a strange behavior. It does not create FedAuth Cookie and seems that the created security token is added to the url instead of a FedAuth cookie. So with the wronge url it gives a Bad request error (HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.). 
I do not know if any configuration is needed on iis or server to use System.IdentityModel dll and SessionAuthenticationModule.

This is a part of my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
  //....
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </configSections>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration/>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" name="PSCID" mode="Chunked" persistentSessionLifetime="30.0:0:0"/>
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>


  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="SPSID" loginUrl="~/account/login" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="~/" domain=""/>
    </authentication>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="error/notfound"/>
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="error/forbidden"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="error/servererror"/>
    </customErrors>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <sessionState cookieName="SID" timeout="2880"/>
    <httpModules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule"/>
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>

    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule"/>
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>

    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  //...
</configuration>
```

In login page after validating username and password I uses this approach to create FedAuth Cookie(s) :

```
var token = new SessionSecurityToken(MyCustomClaimsPrincipal.GetInstance(username, roles,claims)            );       
token.IsPersistent=rememberMe;

var sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
sam.IsReferenceMode = true;
sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);
```

After deploy on server and a successfull login the url is like this:

```
http//w1.mydomain.com/account/8dPbsEZgZ6kV660tL8n8fsqHio.... [a big token here]
```

What am I doing wrong?